# Confusion with mocking stateless React component helper functions with sinon, enyzme, and ES6 imports

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sinon

I'm currently trying to unit test a React component and have run into some confusion about mocking functions the helper functions. The module looks something like this

```
export const someHelper = () => {
  return ( <div></div> )
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <span>
      {someHelper()}
    </span>
  )
}
export default MyComponent
```

and then this is what the test file looks like

```
import chai, { expect } from 'chai'
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import React from 'react'

import MyComponent, { someHelper } from './MyComponent'

describe('MyComponent test', function (){
  it.only('should call someHelper once', function () {
    let spy = sinon.spy(someHelper)
    let myComponent = shallow(
      <MyComponent />
    )
    expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1)
  })
})
```

This test fails however as callCount equals 0. I figured that maybe it had something to do with the context of the `someHelper` function, so I made these changes

```
export const helpers = {
  someHelper () {
    ...
  }
}
const MyComponent = () => {
   ...
   {helpers.someHelper()}
   ...
}
```

_

```
import MyComponent, { helpers } ...

describe(...{
  it(...{
    let spy = sinon.spy(helpers.someHelper)
     ...
  })
})
```

But this test still fails with callCount equaling 0. I then made these changes

```
describe(...{
  it(...{
    let spy = sinon.spy(helpers, 'someHelper')
     ...
  })
})
```

And then test now passes.

Why do I have to attach `someHelper` to the `helpers` object for this test to work? And why do I have to use that last `spy(object, 'myfunc')` method when the [sinon docs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) show a `spy(myFunc)` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I have to attach `someHelper` to the `helpers` object for this test to work?

Sinon has to be able to replace the reference to the existing function with a spy/stub-wrapped version of it, and it can only do so when that reference is stored in an object (`helpers` in this case).

It basically does this:

```
let functionToSpyOn = helpers.someHelper;
let spy = sinon.spy(functionToSpyOn);
helpers.someHelper = spy;
```

The additional complication here is that the original code has to call the function through this reference, so something like this won't work either:

```
const someHelper     = () => { ... }
export const helpers = { someHelper }
const MyComponent    = () => {
   ...
   {someHelper()}
   ...
}
```

The reason being that `MyComponent` doesn't use the reference that is stored in `helpers`, which is the one getting replaced by Sinon. That's why the component needs to use `helpers.someHelper()`.

> And why do I have to use that last `spy(object, 'myfunc')` method...

This again has to do with replacing the function with a wrapped version of it.

> ...when the sinon docs show a `spy(myFunc)` option?

I find that this idiom is generally of limited use. It doesn't, as you may think, spy on all calls to `myFunc` *unless* those calls are made to the spy object that is the result of `spy()`.

For instance:

```
let callback = (err, result) => { ... }
...
let spy = sinon.spy(callback);
someFuncToTest(spy);
expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1);
```

So instead of passing the callback function directly, the spy is passed.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! So would there really be no way to stub a function that is called directly and not through some object (i.e. helpers)?

Comment: @Weston not with Sinon directly, but [`rewire`](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) and [`babel-plugin-rewire`](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) may be able to help you out (the former probably not so much because it doesn't work with Babel).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't specific to React or Sinon but to JS in general.

If something like this happens

```
var spiedMethod = (...args) => {
  console.log('spy!');
  return object.method(...args);
};
```

this creates a new function that doesn't replace the original `object` method. If `object.method` is called, `spiedMethod` won't be called - the original method will be. To replace it on `object`, the object should be modified:

```
object.method = spiedMethod;
```

This is exactly what Sinon spies do.

```
let spy = sinon.spy(myFunc);
```

returns `sinon.spy(myFunc)` a spy for provided function. In order for the call to be spied, `spy` should be called instead of `myFunc`.

Unless something like this is done

```
helpers.someHelper = sinon.spy(helpers.someHelper);
```

there is no way how Sinon can associate `spy` function with spied method. This is where

```
sinon.spy(helpers, 'someHelper')
```

comes to the rescue. It essentially does `helpers.someHelper = spy` but also saves the original method internally, so it can do `helpers.someHelper = someHelperOriginal` when `helpers.someHelper.restore()` is called.